# I am trying to solve this question i can't find what (char*)ptr2 - (char*)ptr1 is returning

Tags: c, generics

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
int *ptr1 = arr;
int *ptr2 = arr + 5;
printf ("ptr2 - ptr1 = %d\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
printf ("(char*)ptr2 - (char*) ptr1 = %d", (char*)ptr2 - (char*)ptr1);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

what (char*)ptr2 is returning after typecasting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr2 - ptr1` is the number of elements between two pointers (in the same array).

`ptr1` is `arr`, i.e. a pointer on the first element of `arr` (equivalent to `&(arr[0])`).
`ptr2` is `arr + 5`, i.e. pointer on the element which is located at five *steps* from the beginning of this array (equivalent to `&(arr[5])`).
In this simple case the difference is obvious: `ptr2-ptr1` is 5 (`arr+5-arr`).

The two conversions to `char *` pretend these two pointers point to `char`s thus `(char *)ptr2 - (char *)ptr1` is the number of *bytes* between the same two elements as before (because in C `sizeof(char)` is one byte).

In your example, there are 5 elements between the two pointers, your platform uses probably 4 bytes for an `int`, then the difference in bytes is 20.

Answer (score 1):

ptr2-ptr1 will give us 5, which implies that there are 5 elements between the two pointers of integer type(4 byte), which is 20(4*5) bytes in total memory, this was the case when compiler was reading memory location with integer pointer, forming a group of 4 byte(integer)each time till 20 bytes,(20/4) which gives 5.

when we typecasted the pointer the same 20 bytes of memory location was interpreted and read  as a single byte value of type char(1 Byte) by the system , thats why it returned 20 bytes.